# Event handler(s) not firing for video tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, event-handling, html5-video

I have a NextJS app where I would display a video file using the `video` element. I am trying to add a bunch of event handlers on it:

```js
<video
  className='video-player'
  controls={true}
  preload='metadata'
  playsInline={true}
  onPlay={(_event) => {
    console.log('video started playing');
    console.log(_event);
  }}
  onPause={(_event) => {
    console.log('video paused');
    console.log(_event);
  }}
  onEnded={(_event) => {
    console.log('video finished');
    console.log(_event);
  }}
  onLoadedData={(_event) => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }}
  onError={(_event) => {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(_event);
  }}>
  <source src={fileView.href} type={mimeType} />
  Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
```

I am not getting any of the `console.log()` for some reason even if I start playing, pausing, and then finishing the video. The `onLoadedData` event handler seems to work fine - the container does scroll to the bottom but the other event handlers (`onPlay`, `onPause`, and `onEnded`) aren't firing at all. I haven't tried the `onError` yet because I don't know how to test it.

Comment: You better create a minimal runnable demo, such as on the `codesandbox` 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @xgqfrms I tried to reproduce using codesandbox and the events are actually firing: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-tsxtn4?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on my local and your codesandbox and both worked fine.

Your code is correct.

If you want to learn more about using video events, see the MDN document [video#events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events)

### test

```
'use client';

import styles from './video.module.css'

function Page() {
  const video = {
    url: "https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/video/woman-car.mp4",
    // url: "https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/video/woman-car",
    type: "video/mp4",
  };
  return (
    <video
      className={styles[`video-player`]}
      controls={true}
      preload='metadata'
      playsInline={true}
      onPlay={(event) => {
        console.log('play ✅');
        // console.log(event);
      }}
      onPause={(event) => {
        console.log('pause ✅✅');
        // console.log(event);
      }}
      onEnded={(event) => {
        console.log('ended ✅✅✅');
        // console.log(event);
      }}
      onLoadedData={(event) => {
        console.log('loadeddata ');
        // scrollToBottom();
      }}
      onError={(event) => {
        console.log('error ❌');
        // console.log(event);
      }}>
      <source src={video.url} type={video.type} />
      Your browser maybe does not support the HTML5 video tag ❌
    </video>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

> screenshots

[image]

[image]